# ADF doesn`t change to CSS :checked state

Tags: html, css, oracle-adf, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I am new to ADF and right now I have a problem with ADF checkboxes and radio buttons customization using CSS.
Here is a demo:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/sbef2so3/16/`
```

Everything works fine in jsfiddle, but in ADF state doesn`t change to :checked.
Maybe there is another approach to change state of the checkbox/radio button in ADF?

**!IMPORTANT. I can`t change HTML code, because it is generated by ADF.**

Comment: I think it does change to `:checked` . . . Is that possible?

Comment: God is good, when I use this code in JDeveloper 11.1.1.7.0, it doesn`t work. When I press radio button nothing happens, it stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

Which component do you use for checkbox or radio buttons.  I used plain HTML tags in my jsf page and added your CSS code and saw same output as your fiddle:

```
<input type="radio" name="..." value="..." />
```

If you use an ADF component, say `selectBooleanRadio`, It's expected to make an [ADF Skin file](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16162_01/user.1112/e17456/toc.htm) which is a superset of CSS and here we write selectors targeting components not DOM elements themselves.  So this is a sample of a skin file:

```
af|selectBooleanRadio::label {
    color: green;
}
```

This fill labels of `selectBooleanRadio` components with green color.

Changing your CSS stylesheet to ADF skin is a non-trivial task, if not impossible due to ADF internal limits.  So by sticking in plain CSS solution, maybe you can get your styles to work by adding `styleClass` to component which may suppress unwanted added styles by current application theme:

```
<af:selectBooleanRadio text="ADF Radio Button" label="Label" styleClass="customRadioButtonComp"/>
```

In your `.css` file add class prefix:

```
.customRadioButtonComp input[type="radio"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 21px;
    height: 21px;
    margin: -1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_ef32e9f2ed5c57aba4c2206a981ba7a4.png)0px top no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    /* Firefox */

    -webkit-appearance: none;
    /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.customRadioButtonComp input[type="radio"]:checked {
    background: url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_ef32e9f2ed5c57aba4c2206a981ba7a4.png)0px bottom no-repeat;
}
```